# Shape - GeoJSON

Tags: geojson

A multiple polygon shape file with some topology errors converted to GeoJSON format, would the topology errors cause problems using the converted file in web maps or apps?

Comment: It depends on what you plan to do. If your app for example tries to calculate area then certainly. If it just about rendering then maybe not.

Comment: test multi-polygon geojson files here http://geojsonlint.com/

Comment: Got this not sure what to do? I got this not sure what it means?

Invalid GeoJSON

Line 1: old-style crs member is not recommended, this object is equivalent to the default and should be removed
Line 6: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule
Line 7: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule
Line 8: Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule
Line 9: Polygons and MultiPolygons should ......continues for all polygons

Comment: Geojsonlint does not like GeoJSON that is created to the original now obsolete specification http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html. The GDAL manual page may clarify a bit. Those errors are not necessarily severe but it depends on software.

Comment: Thanks all, here is another test site that hoogw posted that doesn't give the right hand rule error http://geojson.io/#map=2/20.0/0.0